# Old Versions Of Opera Mobile Emulator

Tags: emulation, opera, opera-mobile

Is it possible to set the version of Opera to use in the Opera Mobile Emulator? I have a pda device where Opera version 10.0 is running and I would like to test my app in an Emulator running exact this version...

I haven't found links to download an older version of the Opera Mobile Emulator, neither have I found a way to set the version in the Emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually old versions of Opera for plenty of different platforms are avaiable on [Opera browser Archives](http://arc.opera.com/pub/opera/). It seems the Opera Mobile emulator is not part of it, I'm not sure why.

after digging a bit.

- [One Windows 7 version](http://arc.opera.com/pub/opera/Win7/1100/)
- [Some versions of "sdlbream"](http://arc.opera.com/pub/opera/sdlbream/) later versions are actually qtbream.
- something apparently called an "android emulator" which looks like it's actually a [widget manager for Windows and Linux](http://arc.opera.com/pub/opera/android/emulator/)

Let me know if that helps… or not. I'll try to dig more.